# vercel not running build and instal commands and not creating Serverless functions

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I am trying to move my application's API to Vercel. It is written in Typescript and uses Express.
The `index.ts` is located in `<root>/src`. The `npm run build` compiles it into `<root>/dist` directory. The file contains the following:

```js
const app = express();
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  //blah, blah, there is a lot going on here
})
app.use('/', common);
//... other app.use(s)

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on ${port}, http://localhost:${port}`));

module.exports = app;
```

I've got the following in the `vercel.json` file which is located in the root directory where the `package.json` also is:

```js
{
  "version": 2,
  "installCommand": "npm install",
  "buildCommand": "npm run build",
  "outputDirectory": "dist",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

When locally I run `npm run build`, then `vercel dev --listen 5000` I get `Ready! Available at http://localhost:5000` and can go to `http://localhost:5000/ping` and get a response.

Now I commit the files to `git`, the deployment runs, but judging by the logs the `npm install` and `npm run build` commands are not running. No functions are created my `/ping` endpoint returns "Page not found".
[image: page not found]
Here is the deployment log:
[image: vercel deployment log]

This is what **Build & Development Settings** look like (the **Root Directory** is left blank):
[image]

I followed several recommendations I found online and according to them everything should work. I probably miss some setting somewhere. What is it?

If more information is needed, please let me know, I'll update my question.
Thank you.

**--- UPDATE ---**

I have set the **Root Directory** to `src` and checked the "*Include source files outside of the Root Directory in the Build Step*" checkbox. Now the `npm install` and `npm run build` are executing. As you can see some static files are deployed, but there are still no serverless functions and my `/ping` route returns 404 and "home" page, i.e. `/` route returns the content of the `index.js` file. In addition the local is not working either anymore, also returning 404 now.

[image]
Without that checkbox I was getting 
`Warning: The vercel.json file should exist inside the provided root directory` 
and still no install or build running.

Also worth noting that I had to change my `tsconfig.json` to have `"outDir": "src/dist"` instead of `"outDir": "dist"`, otherwise I was getting 
`Error: No Output Directory named "dist" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.`

Removed the Root directory and back to square one, no npm commands running but local is working with `/` route returning `Cannot GET /` and `/ping` returning correct response.

Comment: Did you solved this situation? I'm facing exactly the same thing... can you update the thread ?

Comment: I tried to summarize my findings as much as possible in the answer below. Did it not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone out there who's looking for an answer, maybe this will help you.

In my case, what I needed is to create a folder, called `api` in my `src` folder, i.e. the folder that is specified as **Root Directory** in **Build & Development Settings** in Vercel. Within this directory, each serverless function needs a file named the same as the path of the route. For example, the file named "my-route.js" will be accessible via `https://my-app-name.vercel.com/api/my-route`.

All this file needs is an import of `index.js` file and `module.exports`. For example:

```js
import app from '../index';
module.exports = app;
```

The `index.js` should also live the Root and contain your express setup.

If you want to have dynamic path parameters, the files' names in the `api` directory should be wrapped in square brakets, like `[my-param.js]`. You can also have sub-directories in the `api` foler.

Here are a few links that helped me figure this out:
https://dev.to/andrewbaisden/how-to-deploy-a-node-express-app-to-vercel-2aa 
https://medium.com/geekculture/deploy-express-project-with-multiple-routes-to-vercel-as-multiple-serverless-functions-567c6ea9eb36 
https://ryanccn.dev/posts/vercel-framework/#path-segments

No changes were needed in my existing Express setup and routes files.

Hope this will help someone. Took me quite a while to figure it all out :)